# Integral $\int\frac{\sin(2zj)}{z(z^{2}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{4})^{2}}dz = 0$ (residues)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Hi guys I'm solving this integral :
$$\int_{+\partial D}\frac{\sin(2zj)}{z(z^{2}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{4})^{2}}dz\,,$$ where $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<\pi \}$

I have found that for $z=0$ the residue is $0$
for $z=\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ ( that are simple poles) the residue are $\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}$  and $\frac{-4}{\pi^{3}}$ so summing every residue the sum is 0 so the integral is $0$. Unfortunately I don't have the solution, and I can't know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Is this a path integral around the circle $|z|=\pi$?

Comment: is on the domain where $|z|<\pi$

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you are integrating with respect to $z$, there needs to be a path of integration, not just a domain of definition. That's like saying $\int x \;dx= 0$ without specifying limits of integration. I think you probably want to write $\oint_Cf(z)\;dx$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=\pi$ traversed counterclockwise, or something like that.

Comment: @MPW this is the integral : https://gyazo.com/e355dbd1c888980b2c129320e9d7f60f

Comment: Yes, note that it is along the boundary of the disk, counterclockwise. That's what "$\partial D+$" means. Actually, I'm not sure what the "+" means. I assume it's an orientation, but it might mean "$D+$" taken to be the upper half or something like that.

Comment: ok , thk you , so i have to take poles that respect |z|<$\pi$ right ? is mi integral right ?

Comment: Yes, I would think that's the correct interpretation. I don't know if the integral is zero or not. Did you work it out?

Comment: @mpw i have done it , and my results are that $\frac{-4}{\pi^{3}}$  and $\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}$  are the resdiudes so summing my residues it cames 0. Unfortunatly i don't have the solution , so i wante to know if my residues are right , and if my integral is right

Comment: Note that $z=0$ is not a pole. It is a removable singularity since $\sin 2jz$ is in the numerator.

Comment: @MPW yes , sorry but i'm italian so i didn't know the name of that type of singularity in english so i just said that the residue is 0 ahaha

Comment: so can you confirm that $\frac{-4}{\pi^{3}}$  and $\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}$  are the residues and the integral is 0 ? ps thk you so much for your help

Comment: The integral evaluates to $0$, your result is correct indeed

Comment: @DavideMorgante thk as always , and the residues are $\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}$  and $\frac{-4}{\pi^{3}}$  right ?

Comment: Yes seems correct!